# Getting string instead of xml response in curl

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have the following curl request

```
$url='http://test/paynetz/epi/fts?login=160&pass=Test@123&ttype=NBFundTransfer&prodid=NSE&amt=50&txncurr=INR&txnscamt=0&clientcode=TkFWSU4%3d&txnid='.urlencode($string).'&date='.urlencode($date).'&custacc=1234567890&udf1=ajeesh&udf2=sam@zz.com&udf3=940000000&udf4=arrackaparmabilhouse&ru=http://www.zwitch.co';
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);  
        echo $auth = curl_exec($curl);
```

Im getting this

```
http://test/paynetz/epi/ftsNBFundTransfer267050dHwIMJR%2FucGOZcnocTnwvISAVaeNZK93Y8veI%2Bb1DtY%3D11
```

Instead of an xml.Im getting the values only not the xml.

I had 505 error inthe response,so I used urlencode($string) instead of $string

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) what URL are you trying to request? `http://test/...` is not likely to succeed unless you have a server named `test` on your network; and 2) are you really trying to request a funds transfer via a CURL request? I can't imagine any bank (or really any company that wants to protect its money) permitting this.

Comment: Thats test I have given for posting here

Comment: @Kryten You may not guess things out of no where with each and every wording in the question

Comment: Regarding the use of `test` in your URL - you should mention that in your question, so we know that's not the problem. Regarding your other comment, I don't know what you're doing (nor do I much care). I'm merely pointing out that it looks like you're trying to make a CURL request to a bank/financial institution website to transfer funds. If that's what you're doing, then it is likely to fail because banks take security very seriously.

Comment: @Kryten I got it working btw.No thanks :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)');` This will confirm that you are a human rather than a bot.

If you are trying to output the XML directly onto a web page, you'll might want to lookup htmlentities().

Comment: Thanks :) There are people who do know things really well :)